# Spark SQL temp table names format restrictions?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a restriction on the format of temp table names allowed in Spark SQL ? I ask this because when I use:

```
json_RDD.registerTempTable("tweet_data")
trends_data=hiveCtx.sql("SELECT * FROM tweet_data")
```

I obtained the following exception:

```
/opt/spark-1.4.1/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
```

but when I used

```
json_RDD.registerTempTable("tweets")
trends_data=hiveCtx.sql("SELECT * FROM tweets")
```

it worked fine. I am using PySpark and the version of Spark is 1.4.1

Answer (score 4):

I have just re-tried your example in Scala (Spark 1.6) and didn't face any error in both cases.

The only restriction on the name of the table is the dot, If the table name has dots (.) in it, please quote the table name with backticks (`).

check [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d9447cac747823e71b676c08c75f4aab34de12a2/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/Catalog.scala#L66) for more details.

Comment: Ok, so maybe the issue is only in PySpark, or the fact that I am using Spark 1.4.1. I will upgrade and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Python related problem. When we read the code they mention that "It is not allowed to specify database name for temporary tables", maybe you have a database called tweet_data ?